# Can PCA scores be used as dependent variable?

Tags: regression, pca, dimensionality-reduction

I am working on a research project where I have several questions from a survey data that measures the same underlying quantity (my dv), possibly each with some measurement error.
I was thinking about using PCA method to extract the most relevant component. My initial analysis turns out to give what I wanted, but I'm not sure if this is a generally accepted practice in statistics. Could someone let me know if there is any problem with this, and if there is any publication that has taken a similar approach?

Thanks a lot

Comment: MAybe this will help http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/33053/incorporating-a-response-variable-in-principal-component-analysis

Comment: Answer to the title question is **yes**: you can use whatever you want as your dependent variable.